# How to replace 'show' with 'download' in rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

This is driving me crazy. Rails is saying I don't have a controller action defined, but I clearly do in `rake routes`.

What am I missing here?

*spec/controllers/api/v1/files_controller_spec.rb:*

```
 describe "download action" do
   after do
     get :download, id: file.id
   end

   it "returns http status 200 OK" do
     expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
   end
 end
```

*Failure message of no route matches action `download`:*

```
 Failures:

   1) Api::V1::FilesController download action returns http status 200 OK
      Failure/Error: get :download, id: file.id

      ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
        No route matches {:action=>"download", :controller=>"api/v1/files", :id=>"2"}
```

*config/routes.rb:*

```
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }  do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :files, only: [:index, :create]
      get "files/:id", to: "file#download", as: "file"

    end
  end
```

*rake routes | grep file:*

```
     api_v1_files  GET   /api/v1/files(.:format)         api/v1/files#index {:format=>:json}
                   POST  /api/v1/files(.:format)         api/v1/files#create {:format=>:json}
       api_v1_file GET   /api/v1/files/:id(.:format)     api/v1/file#download {:format=>:json}
```

Comment: Did you define a public method `download` in your `API::V1::FilesController`?

Comment: no not yet, trying to TDD this thing.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe your way would have worked, too, if you had written `to: "files#download"` instead (plural).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add more routes to a resource with a block like so:

```
resources :files, only: [:index, :create] do
  member do 
    get 'download'
  end
end
```

Comment: The official Rails Guide on routing is really good and explains this in detail: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: this answer worked.  not sure what I did wrong, but the block format is definitely nicer. +1